# Programmatically changing text size is preventing change event

Tags: jquery

We have a textbox where the user is supposed to enter some data. However, that data must not exceed 500 characters. In order to accomplished that we've implemented the following function called on the KeyUp event:

```
        function keyupMaxLimit(obj, maxlen) {
            if (parseInt(obj.value.length) > maxlen) {
                $(obj).val($(obj).val().substr(0,maxlen));
            }
        }
```

This is working: the user is unable to enter more that is supposed to.
We also have a function associated to the Change event of the same textbox, in order to detect changes and do our magic.

```
    $(document).on("change", "#myTextBox", function () {
        //magic here
    });
```

This is also working: when the user changes the text the function is being called.

However, and this is our problem, this two functions are not working together. If, for instance, the user introduces more characters that he/she is supposed to, the first function will trim the text but the second one will not be called!

It appears that the changes we do to the textbox on the first function is preventing/clearing the Change event. Is this correct? Any workaround? I cannot explicitly trigger the Change event on the first function because we would create unnecessary changes.

EDIT - You can see this happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpaires/dpujx/
Open the browser's console and write "12345" on the textbox. The event will be triggered ("a-ok" on the console). However, if you write "123456" the text will be cut and the event will NOT be triggered (no "a-ok" on the console). Thanks Juhana :)

Comment: Assuming that the "magic" is just `keyupMaxLimit(this, 500);` it should work fine.  There's nothing there that will clear an event handler

Comment: your keyup event may have some mistakes..please show us that code...too

Comment: @Archer Yes, it is. In my textarea tag I have the atribute as follows: onkeyup="keyupMaxLimit(this, 500);

Comment: @axrwkr In my textarea tag I have the atribute as follows: onkeyup="keyupMaxLimit(this, 500);

Comment: Get rid of the inline `onkeyup` and change the `change` event handler in your script to a `keyup` event handler.

Comment: You do know that the change event won't trigger until the input field loses focus? So it won't trigger as often as the keyup event.

Comment: @Juhana Yes, I know that and that is exactly what I'm looking for :) However, the event is not trigger at all (including after the field loses focus).

Comment: Norepro: http://jsfiddle.net/BdqDB/ There's something else in your code causing the problem that you're not showing us.

Comment: @Juhana Notice that if you change the limit to 5 (instead of 500) and write "12345" you'll get the event ("a-ok") but if you try to write "123456" the text will be cut to "12345" and you will not get the event. Right ?

Comment: Good point! It seems that `.val()` resets some flag that makes the browser think the field hasn't been changed.

Comment: Not only the .val(), I've tried with pure javascript (obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, maxlen) ) and the problem remains.

Comment: @op when I type the 6th character and quickly press enter (fade out) it still fires the event

Comment: also if you include `$(obj).change();` in the if statement it works without fading out:  http://jsfiddle.net/jpaires/dpujx/

Comment: @user2264587 That is correct, and I've gave it a thought, however I only want the Change event to occur after leaving the textbox, and not every time the text is cut. Otherwise, I may end up doing my "magic" too soon.

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/dpujx/1/ ?

Comment: @user2264587 Well, I guess it's a valid workaround. Many thanks for your time. That said, I think that the main question remains: why is this workaround need in the first place?

Answer (score -3):

I should give a try to limit the number of characters in html input like this instead:

```
<input type="text" id="Textbox" name="Textbox" maxlength="500" />
```

Other thing is if you want to do something when the text input change, and i think that in this case you can use the keyup event on the input also, like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#myTextBox", function () {
 //SOMETHING
});
```

I updated this fiddle with my sugestion and it works...
http://jsfiddle.net/BdqDB/

By this way you fire always the log and the text is limited.

The other solution is: 
If you want to keep using your function to cut text i would do like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#myTextBox", function () {
  keyupMaxLimit(this,5);
  console.log('other stuff');
});
```

See this working on http://jsfiddle.net/wTQa4/1/

If you check jquery change documentation you can find:
"*The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.*"

So i think that the answer to this question is, you wont get what you want through the change event, i gave you a solution to your problem but you didn't send feedback...
Other thing that you shouldn't do is to call js methods inline, once you're using jQuery, is very easy to bind events to elements and it's unobtrusive javascript, a best practice to write js.

Comment: Just trying to help, avoiding one function to do a thing that a property of input does and get 3 votes down?! Very interesting....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's ok to suggest alternative routes but you should do so in the comments. It's also ok in answers but you have to answer the actual question as well ("Your code doesn't work because blah blah, you can fix it by changing foo to bar, although the easiest way would be to use the maxlength attribute instead.")

Comment: Using the maxlength seens to have no effect.